# Custom Comparator Argument using Java Lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I have some Java code that sorts a list of objects by last modified time in descending order:

```
lists=lists.stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ObjModel::getModifiedtime).reversed())
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This works fine, but I'd like to have custom sorting using a method argument:

```
public void getLists(final String sortBy) { }
```

Assuming that `sortBy` will be `modifiedtime`, how can I adjust the lambda to work with this?

I'm thinking I need to use Java reflection but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm having trouble envisioning what "getLists" is supposed to do or sort by.  Can you elaborate?  Give an example?

Comment: @markspace sure, it will return a list of shopping list objects sorted by last modified time

Comment: In that case, you need to use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is a bad idea. Your method should be :

```
  public List<ObjModel> getLists(Comparator<ObjModel> sortby) {
      return lists.stream().sorted(sortby).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

With that method, you can use a lambda in argument to decide which field of ObjModel class you want to use to sort the list